# Formula to Check if Objects are Mapped to People

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to check whether a person (Column A) has a specific kind of object (Column B) associated with them, where people form one column and objects form another?  To explain further, a person may have multiple objects associated with them, and for all of those objects if even one matches some value then I would like a third column to display the value 1.  I'm imagining that some kind of `INDEX(MATCH())` style statement nested in an IF might work, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Do you mean objects in the spreadsheet, such as Shapes and Charts? Or is Objects some field in your table? This is unclear. It would also help if you provided some sample data and what output you expect from that data.

Comment: @eXCELLL Sorry, I meant fields - I tried to clarify that a bit just now.  I did mean to provide sample data but I'm not allowed to post images.  I'll write out a basic example instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Pivot Table for this.  Formulas are not necessary and you will enjoy much greater flexibility.

I would add Object to the Filter, add Person to the Rows, and add Object to the Values, which will produce "Count of Object".  Then you can filter the Person and/or the Object to see your counts.

You could also filter the Person field using a Value Filter to test the "Count of Object" result.